# UIWindow convertRect: fromView:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Can someone tell me how this works on iPad?  Is it different from how it works on iPhone?

```
CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
```

It get weird heights from textFieldRect.size.height.  All seems normal until about the middle of the view.  The size.height shrinks to a very low number, and bounces back and forth as my cursor goes down the view.

Answer (score 0):

There's some good explanations in here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/38908-can-someone-please-explain-how-convertrect-fromview-method.html

If you were to colour the view for debugging purposes and then compare what it is currently doing versus what you want/expect, I think this will help you.